# Visual Studio Code extension configuration error with Linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

Help me guys about this error!

[image]

how can i get rid of it?

What is the configuration of c_cpp_propertioes.json file in Linux?

Comment: Error for `#include <iostream>` is "cannot open source file "stddef.h" (dependency of "iostream")"  -- better to include full error text in your question. What is your linux (ubuntu/debian/???) and version? Did you install `build-essential` package? Can you compile simple c++ test programs with g++ in console?

Comment: `stddef.h` is a standard include file. On Debian (and probably Ubuntu) it's in the `linux-libc-dev` package. Make sure that's installed.

Comment: @osgx. Yup, i can compile all the programs with g++ in console.  And i'm using Linux mint 18 which is based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: @RAHULTRIVEDI, check that your `c_cpp_properties.json` file of vscode (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp  - C/Cpp: Edit Configurations command from the Command Palette & Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md) has all needed paths to include directories (try running g++ or clang++ on the example with `-H` option to get actual header search paths). Recommendation found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855519/ by searching for error message. Probably VSCode have no idea of exact path into your version of g++ or clang++ internal compiler include dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "update your includePath" can happen for a variety of reasons, but in general it means that your VSCode C++ configuration needs to be adjusted (but not necessarily `includePath` itself).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742056/2659307) contains generic instructions on how to configure VSCode for C++.