# I don't know where the lib files are for c in windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

This is the c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"         <-- need to change this
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I need to find the path for libraries so I can run the code written in c

Comment: Can you take that define, place it in a variable/macro/define and print it?  Not elegant, but should work.

Comment: You might not need to configure this manually.  In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742056/2659307) I explain the basic procedure for configuring VSCode to work with C++, including if and how to manually the includePath.