# VS Code, GCC(MinGW/WinLibs), Win10: #include <dirent.h> -> "#include errors detected. Please update your IncludePath", BUT #include "[abs path]" is OK

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-studio-code, mingw

**[SOLVED]**

Environment used:

- **Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 10.0.19042**
- **Visual Studio Code, 1.54.3**
- **C/C++ Extension for Visual Studio Code, Version 1.2.2: February 25, 2021**
- **MinGW-w64 8.0.0**
  (I'm trying also WinLibs package with GCC 10.2.0 +
  LLVM/Clang/LLD/LLDB 11.0.0 + MinGW-w64 8.0.0)

**Briefly, the problem is:**
When I try to #include <dirent.h>, it is failed with the error:    cannot open source file "dirent.h", 
BUT #include "C:\Program    Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\dirent.h" to    the file is working.

Screenshots of two cases are: 
(sorry, I am not allowed to embed images yet, please open the links to the screenshots):
[#include <dirent.h> -> failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bltIf.png)
[#include "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\dirent.h" -> included, no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gjPY.png)

If include the file by the absolute path specified, the code is compiled and working.

Strange thing is that nearly placed **direct.h** header under the "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" directory may be included with no specifying the absolute path.
IntelliSense helps to include it:
[#include <direct.h>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syVHa.png)

My config files must be well-configured, since compilation and GDB debugging are working well. 
I have two configurations: GCC and Win32 (MSVC compiler).

> c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "GCC",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            //"compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            ...
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Variations of "includePath": ["C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include**"] doesn't help (without * symbols at all or with one symbol).
direct.h can be found without adding includePath values. I read somewhere that compilerPath makes environment asking the compiler about headers available.
Also, I tried to change "cStandard": "c11" to other values: "gcc11", for example. It doesn't help.

I also tried to set the value of C_Cpp.default.includePath in workspace.codeworkspace file:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        //"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
        "C_Cpp.default.includePath": ["C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include"]
    },
}
```

> tasks.json:

```
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        // "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            // Add debug info (-g option) to the object file (files) and link to exe (-o option)
            "-g",
            "${fileDirname}\\**.c",
            // "${fileDirname}\\**.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
          ],
        "options": {
            //"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: \"C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe\""
        //"detail": "compiler: \"C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe\""
    }
```

Code of C language which uses dirent.h is simple (again, it is compiled successfully if the absolute path is specified, so it must not be related to the problem, just in case):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\dirent.h"
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    DIR *dir1;
    struct dirent *dirEntry;
    dir1 = opendir(".");
    if (dir1)
    {
        while ((dirEntry = readdir(dir1)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", dirEntry->d_name);
        }
        closedir(dir1);
    }

    getchar();
}
```

PATH environment variable is set to the GCC compiler's path:
[PATH variable -> GCC compiler path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfZnq.png)

**Could anyone help with it please? Or give any information what may be wrong?
Why direct.h can be found correctly, but dirent.h is not? (and other headers also)**

**Thank you for any help and information.**

Comment: You need to set the include path in both `c_cpp_properties.json` and `tasks.json` in tasks.json the `-I` parameter of gcc specifies the path. The `includePath` in `c_cpp_properties.json` is only used for intellisense I believe

Comment: @drescherjm thanks a lot for your answer. I added the path to tasks.json in this format: "args": ["-IC:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include" ...] And to c_cpp_properties.json: "includePath": ["C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include"... The program compiled successfully, but the Problems tab shows the problems of including anyway. Also, IntelliSense doesn't help with <dirent.h>. Will try to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you, the problem solved with this answer: [vscode "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227662/vscode-include-errors-detected-please-update-your-includepath/57742056#57742056)
The reason was in that I had several configurations (Win32 of MSVC compiler also). For some reason, Win32 configuration was used instead of GCC configuration.
**Useful thing:** Ctrl + P-> **"C/C++: Log Diagnostics"**, it shows output of your current configuration, PATHs used. Now, -I option and IncludePath parms are not required. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem solved, the solution and useful tips:**
The reason was in that I had several configurations (Win32 of MSVC compiler along with GCC). For some reason, Win32 configuration was used instead of GCC configuration. Despite that compilation was successful after setting -I and IncludePath, #include <...> was not working well because another configuration was used (Win32 of MSVC compiler). As a result, Problem tab was notifying about #include problems detected. And IntelliSense wasn't helping to include headers. 
**Useful thing to check your current configuration**:
Ctrl + P-> "C/C++: Log Diagnostics", it shows output of your current configuration and which PATHs are used.

A good detailed answer about #include issues is here:
[vscode "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227662/vscode-include-errors-detected-please-update-your-includepath/57742056#57742056)

Now, I commented Win32 configuration. I do not know if there is an option to set a configuration by default.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "GCC",
            "includePath": [
            //    "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
        // {
        //     "name": "Win32",
...
        //     "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
        //     "cStandard": "c11",
        //     "cppStandard": "c++17",
        //     "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        // },
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Output of "C/C++: Log Diagnostics":
("Output" tab can be opened by Ctrl + Shift + U by defaul)

```
-------- Diagnostics - 3/20/2021, 1:38:20 AM
Version: 1.2.2
Current Configuration:
{
    "name": "GCC",
    "includePath": [],
...
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
    }
}
Translation Unit Configurations:
[ C:\Users\[USER]\C Projects\TestProgram\TestFile.c ]:
    Process ID: 6876
    Memory Usage: 14 MB
    Compiler Path: C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
    Includes:
        C:\PROGRAM FILES\MINGW-W64\X86_64-8.1.0-POSIX-SEH-RT_V6-REV0\MINGW64\LIB\GCC\X86_64-W64-MINGW32\8.1.0\INCLUDE
        C:\PROGRAM FILES\MINGW-W64\X86_64-8.1.0-POSIX-SEH-RT_V6-REV0\MINGW64\LIB\GCC\X86_64-W64-MINGW32\8.1.0\INCLUDE-FIXED
        C:\PROGRAM FILES\MINGW-W64\X86_64-8.1.0-POSIX-SEH-RT_V6-REV0\MINGW64\X86_64-W64-MINGW32\INCLUDE
    Defines:
        _DEBUG
        UNICODE
        _UNICODE
    Standard Version: c11
    IntelliSense Mode: windows-gcc-x64
    Other Flags:
        --gcc
        --gnu_version=80100
Total Memory Usage: 55 MB
```